# Route 404 when running Spring Boot MVC in IntelliJ 15

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a very simple example from [Mastering Spring MVC 4](https://www.packtpub.com/packtlib/book/All%20Books/9781783982387) in IntelliJ 15.0.2. I can get the example to run properly with `./gradlew bootRun` from the command line, but not from IntelliJ.

When I run the application with `./gradlew bootRun` I see the template at `http://localhost:8080`. When I run the application via `Run` in IntelliJ, the application appears to launch properly, but I receive the white label 404 page.

Application

```
package masterSpringMvc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MasterSpringMvcApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MasterSpringMvcApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller in `src/main/java/masterSpringMvc/controller`

```
package masterSpringMvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String hello() {
        return "resultPage";
    }
}
```

Template in `src/main/resources/templates`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Hello thymeleaf</title>
</head>
<body>
<span th:text="|Hello thymeleaf|">Hello html</span>
</body>
</html>
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.3.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot' 

jar {
    baseName = 'masterSpringMvc'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.9'
}
```

./gradlew bootRun

```
% ./gradlew bootRun                                                                                                                                       
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources
:classes
:findMainClass
:bootRun

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)

2016-01-12 10:18:36.263  INFO 8812 --- [           main] m.MasterSpringMvcApplication             : Starting MasterSpringMvcApplication on duffn with PID 8812 (/Users/nickduffy/Dropbox/Development/learning/java/MasterMvc/build/classes/main started by nickduffy in /Users/nickduffy/Dropbox/Development/learning/java/MasterMvc)
2016-01-12 10:18:36.266  INFO 8812 --- [           main] m.MasterSpringMvcApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-01-12 10:18:36.503  INFO 8812 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5204062d: startup date [Tue Jan 12 10:18:36 MST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-12 10:18:36.942  INFO 8812 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-01-12 10:18:37.493  INFO 8812 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-01-12 10:18:37.503  INFO 8812 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-01-12 10:18:37.504  INFO 8812 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
2016-01-12 10:18:37.574  INFO 8812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-01-12 10:18:37.574  INFO 8812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1074 ms
2016-01-12 10:18:37.797  INFO 8812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-01-12 10:18:37.801  INFO 8812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-12 10:18:37.802  INFO 8812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-12 10:18:37.802  INFO 8812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-12 10:18:37.802  INFO 8812 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-12 10:18:38.046  INFO 8812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@5204062d: startup date [Tue Jan 12 10:18:36 MST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-12 10:18:38.112  INFO 8812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String masterSpringMvc.controller.HelloController.hello()
2016-01-12 10:18:38.115  INFO 8812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-01-12 10:18:38.115  INFO 8812 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-01-12 10:18:38.137  INFO 8812 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-01-12 10:18:38.137  INFO 8812 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-01-12 10:18:38.164  INFO 8812 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-01-12 10:18:38.553  INFO 8812 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-01-12 10:18:38.625  INFO 8812 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-01-12 10:18:38.629  INFO 8812 --- [           main] m.MasterSpringMvcApplication             : Started MasterSpringMvcApplication in 2.608 seconds (JVM running for 2.907)
> Building 80% > :bootRun
```

bootRun request that succeeds

```
2016-01-12 10:29:30.798  INFO 9103 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-01-12 10:29:30.803  INFO 9103 --- [           main] m.MasterSpringMvcApplication             : Started MasterSpringMvcApplication in 2.753 seconds (JVM running for 3.068)
2016-01-12 10:29:36.617  INFO 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-01-12 10:29:36.617  INFO 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-01-12 10:29:36.628  INFO 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 11 ms
2016-01-12 10:29:36.644 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@751fc5a9
2016-01-12 10:29:36.671 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF] INITIALIZING TEMPLATE ENGINE
2016-01-12 10:29:36.709 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.t.t.AbstractTemplateResolver           : [THYMELEAF] INITIALIZING TEMPLATE RESOLVER: org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.TemplateResolver
2016-01-12 10:29:36.710 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.t.t.AbstractTemplateResolver           : [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE RESOLVER INITIALIZED OK
2016-01-12 10:29:36.710 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.t.m.AbstractMessageResolver            : [THYMELEAF] INITIALIZING MESSAGE RESOLVER: org.thymeleaf.spring4.messageresolver.SpringMessageResolver
2016-01-12 10:29:36.710 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.t.m.AbstractMessageResolver            : [THYMELEAF] MESSAGE RESOLVER INITIALIZED OK
2016-01-12 10:29:36.714 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.CONFIG      : [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURATION:
[THYMELEAF] * Cache Factory implementation: org.thymeleaf.cache.StandardCacheManager
[THYMELEAF] * Template modes:
[THYMELEAF]     * HTML5
[THYMELEAF]     * VALIDXHTML
[THYMELEAF]     * LEGACYHTML5
[THYMELEAF]     * XML
[THYMELEAF]     * XHTML
[THYMELEAF]     * VALIDXML
[THYMELEAF] * Template resolvers (in order):
[THYMELEAF]     * org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.TemplateResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Message resolvers (in order):
[THYMELEAF]     * org.thymeleaf.spring4.messageresolver.SpringMessageResolver
[THYMELEAF] * Dialect [1 of 2]: org.thymeleaf.spring4.dialect.SpringStandardDialect
[THYMELEAF]     * Prefix: "th"
[THYMELEAF] * Dialect [2 of 2]: nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect
[THYMELEAF]     * Prefix: "layout"
[THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE CONFIGURED OK
2016-01-12 10:29:36.714 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF] TEMPLATE ENGINE INITIALIZED
2016-01-12 10:29:36.904 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@751fc5a9
2016-01-12 10:29:37.448 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@751fc5a9
2016-01-12 10:29:37.459 DEBUG 9103 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@751fc5a9
> 2016-01-12 10:33:50.354  INFO 9103 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@376b4233: startup date [Tue Jan 12 10:29:28 MST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

IntelliJ Run

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)

2016-01-12 10:19:32.964  INFO 8837 --- [           main] m.MasterSpringMvcApplication             : Starting MasterSpringMvcApplication on duffn with PID 8837 (/Users/nickduffy/Dropbox/Development/learning/java/MasterMvc/build/classes/main started by nickduffy in /Users/nickduffy/Dropbox/Development/learning/java/MasterMvc)
2016-01-12 10:19:32.967  INFO 8837 --- [           main] m.MasterSpringMvcApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-01-12 10:19:33.016  INFO 8837 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@587c290d: startup date [Tue Jan 12 10:19:33 MST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-12 10:19:33.904  INFO 8837 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-01-12 10:19:34.431  INFO 8837 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-01-12 10:19:34.442  INFO 8837 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-01-12 10:19:34.442  INFO 8837 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
2016-01-12 10:19:34.506  INFO 8837 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-01-12 10:19:34.506  INFO 8837 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1494 ms
2016-01-12 10:19:34.718  INFO 8837 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-01-12 10:19:34.721  INFO 8837 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-12 10:19:34.721  INFO 8837 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-12 10:19:34.721  INFO 8837 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-12 10:19:34.721  INFO 8837 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-01-12 10:19:34.892  INFO 8837 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@587c290d: startup date [Tue Jan 12 10:19:33 MST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-01-12 10:19:34.936  INFO 8837 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String masterSpringMvc.controller.HelloController.hello()
2016-01-12 10:19:34.939  INFO 8837 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-01-12 10:19:34.940  INFO 8837 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-01-12 10:19:34.959  INFO 8837 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-01-12 10:19:34.959  INFO 8837 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-01-12 10:19:34.985  INFO 8837 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-01-12 10:19:35.059  INFO 8837 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-01-12 10:19:35.113  INFO 8837 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-01-12 10:19:35.117  INFO 8837 --- [           main] m.MasterSpringMvcApplication             : Started MasterSpringMvcApplication in 2.446 seconds (JVM running for 2.858)
```

IntelliJ request that 404s

```
2016-01-12 10:33:56.916  INFO 9305 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-01-12 10:33:56.920  INFO 9305 --- [           main] m.MasterSpringMvcApplication             : Started MasterSpringMvcApplication in 2.494 seconds (JVM running for 2.842)
2016-01-12 10:34:04.328  INFO 9305 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-01-12 10:34:04.328  INFO 9305 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2016-01-12 10:34:04.337  INFO 9305 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 9 ms
2016-01-12 10:34:04.348 DEBUG 9305 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7a29e417
2016-01-12 10:34:04.370 DEBUG 9305 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7a29e417
2016-01-12 10:34:04.880 DEBUG 9305 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7a29e417
2016-01-12 10:34:04.886 DEBUG 9305 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@7a29e417
```

The only item in my `Run` configuration is Main class: masterSpringMvc.MasterSpringMvcApplication.

What else do I need to add to my configuration in IntelliJ to be able to launch the app successfully?

Comment: Have you turned on debugging to see what routes are being created at start time and then also to see what routes your request is checked against?  What does your SpringBoot Application runner configuration look like in intelliJ?  Are you using embedded tomcat?

Comment: I've added some more information.

Comment: Do you see all the starter libraries in your project? Try re-importing the libraries and rebuilding the project. (See https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html on how to do that)

Comment: That was it @jny. I'll accept if you want to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the IDEA project has not been updated with some dependencies and  `Spring Boot` auto-configuration is not picking up all the dependencies from the classpath.

Try reimporting your libraries and rebuilding the project. See [IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html) documentation on how to do that with `Gradle`.