# Cannot open index page in Thymeleaf, getting 404 in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

I've created simple demo for Spring boot and Thymeleaf, but I cannot open index page.

Controller code:

```
package com.jrp.demo.web;
 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 
@Controller
public class HomeController {
 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Having index template in `/src/main/resources/templates/index.html`

Having application.properties:

`server.port=9095`

And going to the address `http://localhost:9095/`

And getting error:

```
2021-12-10 11:08:32.200 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2021-12-10 11:08:32.200 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.jrp.demo.web.HomeController#home()
2021-12-10 11:08:32.201 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2021-12-10 11:08:32.201 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'index', model {}
2021-12-10 11:08:32.201 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [index]
2021-12-10 11:08:32.201 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "FORWARD" dispatch for GET "/index", parameters={}
2021-12-10 11:08:32.202 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
2021-12-10 11:08:32.204 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Resource not found
2021-12-10 11:08:32.204 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "FORWARD" dispatch, status 404
2021-12-10 11:08:32.204 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2021-12-10 11:08:32.204 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2021-12-10 11:08:32.207 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2021-12-10 11:08:32.220 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2021-12-10 11:08:32.220 DEBUG 11124 --- [nio-9095-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
```

Spring boot class is:

```
package com.jrp.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and pom.xml contains spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf and spring-boot-starter-web.

Comment: Can you please show me your `index.html` and `application.properties`

Comment: Also are your resources packaged correctly? Check the content of your `target` folder. If the html template is not present there under path you have in your controller - try to clean rebuild your app and consider checking your `Maven Resources` plugin (if you use it)

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej `application.properties` are described in question (only `server.port` is there) and `index.html` contains only `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is index page</h1>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: @PavelPolyakoff I've run `clean install` on project and looked for `index.html` in target and found it on path `..\demo1\target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\BOOT-INF\classes\templates\` but have not found it directly in `target`, is it wrong? P.s. currently maven resources plugin is not configured in the project.

Comment: And could you please show your MVC configuration class? The one where you have your `template resolver` bean configured. Usually it's a `@Configuration` class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer`. If you did not create that - chances are your Spring has no idea that the return of your controller method is a path to a template

Comment: @PavelPolyakoff, I have dependency to `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf`, so as said on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc#thymeleaf-in-spring-boot) no explicit configuration is need and HTML files have to be in `resources/templates` here is my [pom.xml](https://pastebin.com/1BEpFWPV).

Comment: Could you please make a demo GitHub project? It would be easier to figure out what’a wrong

Comment: @PavelPolyakoff, I've pushed project [here](https://github.com/lidiya-pabalavets-embedit-cz/demo1)

Comment: Weird, works fine for me, no errors. Try to re-import the project from Git maybe.

Comment: Thank you, @PavelPolyakoff, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34770479/2363662), Intellij IDEA had outdated dependencies, so helped buttons `Reload all maven projects` and `Generate sources and update folders for all projects`. [image]